# How to bind a JSpinner to a Map?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

My GUI have several `JSpinner` instances, and I have an `EnumMap`. I want to "bind" each spinner to my Map, I mean, if `jSpinner1` change his value, it should also change the value of the map with `key1`.

I don't want to do this manually for each jSpinners :

```
private void jSpinner1StateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {

    Integer val = (Integer) jSpinner1.getValue(); 
    data.setValue(enumKey1, val);
}
```

How could I do it correctly?

---

Yes, a factory is the best solution I think:

```
spinners = Arrays.asList(/*add jSpinners in the same order as the KeySet*/);


private void jSpinnerFactory() {
    int i=0;
    for (final Pic key : Pic.values()) {       //Pic.values(): keySet
        JSpinner js = spinners.get(i);
        js.addChangeListener(new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt) {
                jSpinnerStateChanged(evt,key);
            }
        });

        i++;
    }
}

private void jSpinnerStateChanged(javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent evt, Pic key) {                                        
    JSpinner js = (JSpinner) evt.getSource();
    data.setValue(key, (Integer) js.getValue());   //data: the object that have the EnumMap
}
```

Comment: A factory method will be enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might simply extend `JSpinner` for a `BoundSpinner`, but I think I'd prefer a factory method to configure each field.

Answer (score 0):

For that purposes you can extend `JSpinner` which will store key for your map(in my example it's `ObjectSpinner`). `Values` is example `enum`, and I use `ChangeListener` for changing value in map.

Here is simple example for you :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.EnumMap;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Example {

    private enum Values{
        v1,v2,v3;
    }

    private EnumMap<Values, Integer> map = new EnumMap<>(Values.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        for(Values v : Values.values()){
            ObjectSpinner<Values> createSpinner = createSpinner(v);
            p.add(createSpinner);
        }

        JButton printResult = new JButton("printResult");
        printResult.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println(map.values());
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(p);
        frame.getContentPane().add(printResult,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private ObjectSpinner<Values> createSpinner(Values value) {
        ObjectSpinner<Values> sp = new ObjectSpinner<Values>(value);
        map.put(value, null);
        sp.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
                ObjectSpinner<Values> spinner = (ObjectSpinner<Values>) arg0.getSource();
                map.put(spinner.getObject(), (Integer) spinner.getValue());
            }
        });
        return sp;
    }

    class ObjectSpinner<T> extends JSpinner{

        private T object;

        public ObjectSpinner(T object){
            super();
            this.object = object;
        }

        public T getObject(){
            return object;
        }

    }

}
```